# Multiple Cell in CollectionView - Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I add data to CollectionViews. It is added smoothly, but as you can see, the same data appears in the sections. For example, 2.section 3 should be different data below. But it only attracts the first three data in the array. I need to pull 4.5.6.string data after the 3rd string that should be. So the problem is the same data is displayed in all sections.

[image]

```
        @objc func kategoriSaydır(){
      if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                      for review in baslik {
                       if let soru_baslik = review["LINK"] as? String {
                          let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                                 self.yeniDavFile.append(s) } }  

 if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
            for review in baslik {
               if let soru_baslik = review["ISIM"] as? String {
                   let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                   self.yeniDavKATIsımNew.append(s) } }
                                              }}

        func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {  return yeniDavKATIsımNew.count   }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       if (collectionView == sonsuzCollec) {
                    return yeniDavKATIsımNew.count
 } }

      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                    let urlNew = URL(string: yeniDavFile[indexPath.item])
                     cell.davetiyeFoto.sd_setImage(with: urlNew) }
```

Comment: how do you defining number of section for collection view?

Comment: I updated topics. The value in the header of the sections is equal, that is, to the values ​​in the newDAVKATIsımNew array @Golukumar

Comment: As you using  *yeniDavKATIsımNew.count* to show number of section so you have to create an nested array in which every index has an array with number of element need to show in collection.

Comment: Thank you, I can't add an array into an array, can't I handle this in a single array?

Comment: do you have fix number of data or dynamic?

Comment: No the number is not fixed, it varies according to the data I have taken from the database. I made it to try numberOfItemsInSection.@Golukumar

Answer (score 0):

yes but you have to keep track of array count and current index. like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let currentIndex = getIndexForArray(with: indexPath)
   if currentIndex < yeniDavFile.count{
      let urlNew = URL(string: yeniDavFile[currentIndex])
      cell.davetiyeFoto.sd_setImage(with: urlNew)
      return cell
  }else{
     return UICollectionViewCell()
  }

}
```

Implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout in your viewcontroller.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
  let currentIndex = getIndexForArray(with: indexPath)
   if currentIndex < yeniDavFile.count{
      return yourCellSize
   }else{
      return .zero
   }
}

func getIndexForArray(with indexPath:IndexPath)->Int{
    var itemIndex = 0
    if indexPath.row != 0{
        for _ in 0..<indexPath.section{
            itemIndex += (collection.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1)
        }
        return (itemIndex + indexPath.row)
    }else{
        return indexPath.row
    }
}
```

this may works

Comment: Thanks, It pulls the first section successfully, but there are 3 data in the second section and the first two data are the same as 1.section, that is, the first two data take the first one. I took the photo on the subject, you can look.

Comment: As I can see your code  you are returning same array count for row and section may be case where array does not  have enough element.

Comment: But I have to take the first 4 in the first section and the next 3 in the second section. Isn't there a way? I checked there are enough items.

Comment: Thank you, but the same problem continues. The first two items in the 2.section are still the same as the 3rd item. the first binary again received the first 2 data, not the 5th and the 6th.

Comment: did you implemented **collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt** in your controller and extended UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout?

Comment: Yes, I did not apply, unfortunately, the result is still not working properly :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212648/discussion-between-deneov-and-golu-kumar).